# React doesn't render second map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object

I'm trying to do second map in a map function. It shows my console.log but doesn't render anything.

Here is my object:

```
  const sidebarItems = [
    {
      icon: DashboardIcon,
      name: 'DASHBOARD',
      path: '/dashboard',
    },
    {
      icon: TaskManagementIcon,
      name: 'TASK MANAGEMENT',
      path: '/task-management',
      subpages: [
        {
          icon: TaskManagementIcon,
          name: 'BOARD VIEW',
          path: 'task-management/board',
        },
        {
          icon: TaskManagementIcon,
          name: 'LIST VIEW',
          path: 'task-management/list',
        },
      ],
    }
  ];
```

And then here is my react component:

```js
function Sidebar({ items, location }) {
  return (
    <div className="app-sidebar">
      <div className="app-sidebar-items">
        {items.map(item => {
          const path = `/app${item.path}`;
          if (path === location.pathname) {
            if (typeof item.subpages !== 'undefined') {
              item.subpages.map(i => {
                return <p>Foo</p>
              });
            }
          }

          return <p>Bar</p>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above code is always showing "Bar" text. The weird thing is, if I do console.log(i), it shows me subitems... Why doesn't it work?

Thanks :)

Comment: Here, react will render whatever you return from the outer `map` function and you're returning just Bar `<p>` tag from outer `map`. That's why, only Bar is rendered.

Comment: What's the better way to do render subitems like this concepts @AjayDabas

Comment: I think it depends on what you exactly want to do and how you want your output to look. One way is to store all subitems in a `<ul>`(or `<ol>`) tag and return that instead of Bar `<p>` tag when your `if` condition is true. But of course, there are other workarounds.

Comment: I want, trigger url changes and show subpages if it has at least one that's why i don't use map function in ```<ul>``` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return` the subpages map. Without that return, the function keeps executing until it gets to `return <p>Bar</p>`, so that's all you'll ever see.

JSX is just pure javascript with some syntax sugar. Rendering JSX only does anything if it's returned.

```
    items.map(item => {
      const path = `/app${item.path}`;
      if (path === location.pathname) {
        if (typeof item.subpages !== 'undefined') {
          return item.subpages.map(i => {
          // ^ added
            return <p>Foo</p>
          });
        }
      }

      return <p>Bar</p>
    })
```

Comment: It actually does work though... https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1ve86